# Add Event Listener to Inner class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an event listener to a 'Subclass' (is that what its called?). But it fails to take effect.

The JS:

```
var Station_Button = function(status_id) 
{
      var alert_txt, class_txt;

      switch( status_id )
      {
        case 1:
        {
            alert_txt = "<strong>Complete!</strong> This Station is complete.";
            class_txt = "alert alert-success";
        }
        case 2:
        {
        alert_txt = "<strong>Error!</strong> This Station has failed!";
            class_txt = "alert alert-info";
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = alert_txt;
      document.getElementById("notify").className = class_txt;
      return false;
}

var ta_butt = document.getElementsByClassName("ta_butt.error");

for(var i=0;i<ta_butt.length;i++)
{
    ta_butt[i].addEventListener('click', function() {Station_Button(2)}, false);
}
```

It works fine, if I take away the .error, but this of course applies the event to all of my 'ta_butt' buttons - I only want it on the ones marked error.

If it interests anyone the CSS:

```
.ta_butt {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size:150%;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0066FF, #4D94FF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0066FF, #4D94FF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #0066FF, #4D94FF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0066FF, #4D94FF); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

.ta_butt.error {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #CC0000, #DB4D4D); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #CC0000, #DB4D4D); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CC0000, #DB4D4D); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CC0000, #DB4D4D); /* Standard     syntax (must be last) */
}

.ta_butt.error:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DB4D4D, #CC0000); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #DB4D4D, #CC0000); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #DB4D4D, #CC0000); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DB4D4D, #CC0000); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: You can use [Curt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32115586/1737627), or use `var ta_butt = document.querySelectorAll(".ta_butt.error");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple classes use a space between the class names:

```
var ta_butt = document.getElementsByClassName("ta_butt error");
```